# Failing to get dependency during SonarScan action

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, sonarqube

In our Java SpringBoot project we are using GitHub actions to run SonarScan. It was working like a charm until I've added first custom library to the project. That library is in Nexus repo and accessible only via VPN.

Locally project is built without any issues and works fine. Unit-testing and dev deployment GH actions run successfully. But SonarScan action is failing on :compileJava because of the missing resource (log below).

Looks like it tries to get it from the Apache Maven although it is in the Nexus. Here is the relevant part of the log:

```
> Task :compileJava
Watching 37 directories to track changes
Resolving global dependency management for project 'project_name'
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/company_name/lib_name/1.0.7-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/company_name/lib_name/1.0.7-SNAPSHOT/lib_name-1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.pom]
Excluding []


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> Task :compileJava FAILED
* What went wrong:
:compileJava (Thread[included builds,5,main]) completed. Took 4 mins 35.418 secs.
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.company_name:lib_name:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.

     Required by:
         project :
      > Skipped due to earlier error
```

Here is our build.gradle file (shortened):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
}


//Sets Java Version
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}

ext {
    set('mongoVersion', '4.4.1')
    set('mavenUsername', "maven.user")
    set('mavenPassword', "password")
    set('mavenUrl', "https://nexus-repo-url/repository/repo-name")
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "${mavenUsername}"
            password "${mavenPassword}"
        }
        url "${mavenUrl}"
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.company_name:lib_name:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT"
}


sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "prject_key"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/classes"
    }
}
```

I am obviously missing some path somewhere, but failing to find where actually.

Comment: As stated in the Gradle documentation (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html) "A project can have multiple repositories. Gradle will look for a dependency in each repository in the order they are specified, stopping at the first repository that contains the requested module." What happens if you try to declare maven (the Nexus repo) first and mavenCentral second?

Comment: How is the VPN configured in the github action? Are you able to reach the nexus repo from the github action at all, i. e. does `curl https://nexus-repo-url/repository/repo-name -u "user:password"` work?

Comment: @qdoot, good catch, but I've tried that already: order has no matter. This change actually changed output logs highlighting that it tried to connect our Nexus and got Connect Timeout. So, that brings up Bragolgirith's point: Is Nexus reach-able from GH actions. Checking.

Comment: run network test through github and nexus. (telnet or curl)

Comment: so if other GH actions can build the project, then the next guess that you need the same networking configs for the Sonar action, maybe that was not set up by you and you missed it? @YehorLevchenko

Comment: Do you have a local ~/.gradle/init.gradle file that contains additional repository information that is used for every build? Does sonarqube maybe override your variables for _mavenUrl_, _mavenUsername_ or _mavenPassword_ somehow? (Are they really stored the way you posted it here? Looks a bit unsecure to me to store credentials directly in the build.gradle file, in plaintext.)

Comment: @Bragolgirith it was indeed the VPN issue. Solved! I can give all the bounty to you since you're just commenting, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Issue was related to the VPN and got fixed in .github/workflows/sonar.yml:

```
name: SonarScan
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - main # or the name of your main branch

jobs:
  build:
    name: SonarScan
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest <-- should be [self-hosted, main] to pass the wall
    steps:
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not resolve com.company_name:lib_name:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.
```

which seems to be populated by

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.company_name:lib_name:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

uneducated guess says you're most likely relying on `com.company_name` and `lib_name` to be supplied as arguments to your code.

which is kind of weird since you're treating it as a dependency, not a parameter.

it's difficult to imagine the context of that application, but checking whether my repo contains com.company_name and/or lib_name etc etc snapshot is where i'd start.

Comment: Not true, dependency is provided as a string, without any variables.

Comment: evidently, as the error contains "com.company_name:lib_name:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT", the aforementioned is provided. you probably want to provide a different string.

Comment: @EverNight I think OP just "obfuscated" the company/lib name, so there is no issue with this

Comment: @vladtkachuk maybe... but i think you're giving him too much credit ... i mean.... people usually mention "i've replaced actual lib names with fake ones", or "path_to_whatever"... + it'd take the kind of autism to make sure that all inconsequential -replaced text is correct across the entire posting that it just defeats the purpose ... so yeah... my money's on him not having obfuscated anything and just copy-pasting boilerplate code from somewhere without understanding much of what's going on

Comment: Solved. All strings are fine, you probably misunderstood the problem. Issue was related to the VPN.